# KeyStore.load throwing IOException on empty .jks file

Tags: java, keystore

I need to create an empty KeyStore file (named KeyStoreAES.jks), and then store an AES SecretKey into that file, all this programatically from Java.

I have this function that creates the .jks file:

```
//Función that creates KeyStoreAES.jks
private static void CreateKeyStoreAES(String path)
{
    try
    {
        //Check if file already exists
        File keyStoreFile = new File(path);

        if (keyStoreFile.exists())
        {
            keyStoreFile.delete();
        } //if

        keyStoreFile.createNewFile();
    } 
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("IOException");
    }
} //CrearKeyStoreAES
```

This function works fine. Then I have another function to insert a key into that file:

```
//Storing Key into KeyStore file
private static void StoreKey(String path, SecretKey key)
{
    try
    {       
        //KeyStore
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS"); //JCEKS, JKS

        //FileInputStream
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);

        //Load KeyStore file
        ks.load(fis, keyStorePass);
    } 
    catch (CertificateException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("CertificateException");
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("IOException");
    }
    catch (KeyStoreException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("KeyStoreException");
    } 
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("NoSuchAlgorithmException");
    } //try
} //StoreKey
```

Calling load function from KeyStore class is throwing IOException. Is this because the file that is trying to load is empty? As far as I have searched on internet, to insert a key into a KeyStore you need to load that file into a KeyStore object.

Comment: Can you post the exception stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, JKS format requires header and trailer information so an empty file is not a valid JKS, and a JKS with no entries is not an empty file.

To create a JKS 'from scratch', **don't load *any* file/data**:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
ks.load(null); // NO INPUTSTREAM HERE
...
ks.setKeyEntry(...); // or .setEntry(...) as desired
...
OutputStream fo = Files.newOutputStream(Path.of("myfile")); // or similar
ks.store(fo,password); fo.close();
```

However, JKS format doesn't support `SecretKey` entries, so this still won't solve your problem. You'll need to use another format like JCEKS or PKCS12, or BouncyCastle's BKS -- all of which also cannot validly be an empty file.

Comment: Thanks. I will use JCEKS then. Hope it all works fine